Slow Boot time on Fedora 39 KDE
On my Fedora 39 KDE, the boot time is too long; it's more than two minutes.
This is the output of the command systemd-analyze:
Startup finished in 6.681s (firmware) + 3.405s (loader) + 1.176s (kernel) + 3.490s (initrd) + 54.218s (userspace) = 1min 8.971s 
graphical.target reached after 54.200s in userspace.

After seeing that the graphical target is taking up the max time to start up, I executed this command sudo systemctl list-dependencies graphical.target. This is the output I get:
graphical.target
● ├─accounts-daemon.service
● ├─power-profiles-daemon.service
● ├─rtkit-daemon.service
● ├─sddm.service
● ├─switcheroo-control.service
○ ├─systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
● ├─udisks2.service
● ├─upower.service
● └─multi-user.target
●   ├─abrt-journal-core.service
●   ├─abrt-oops.service
○   ├─abrt-vmcore.service
●   ├─abrt-xorg.service
●   ├─abrtd.service
●   ├─atd.service
×   ├─auditd.service
●   ├─avahi-daemon.service
●   ├─chronyd.service
●   ├─crond.service
●   ├─cups.path
●   ├─firewalld.service
○   ├─flatpak-add-fedora-repos.service
●   ├─irqbalance.service
○   ├─livesys-late.service
○   ├─livesys.service
●   ├─lm_sensors.service
●   ├─mcelog.service
○   ├─mdmonitor.service
●   ├─ModemManager.service
●   ├─mysqld.service
●   ├─NetworkManager.service
●   ├─plymouth-quit-wait.service
●   ├─plymouth-quit.service
●   ├─postgresql.service
●   ├─rsyslog.service
●   ├─smartd.service
○   ├─sssd.service
●   ├─systemd-ask-password-wall.path
●   ├─systemd-homed.service
●   ├─systemd-logind.service
●   ├─systemd-oomd.service
○   ├─systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
●   ├─systemd-user-sessions.service
●   ├─teamviewerd.service
○   ├─vboxservice.service
●   ├─basic.target
●   │ ├─-.mount
●   │ ├─tmp.mount
●   │ ├─paths.target
●   │ ├─slices.target
●   │ │ ├─-.slice
●   │ │ └─system.slice
●   │ ├─sockets.target
●   │ │ ├─avahi-daemon.socket
●   │ │ ├─cups.socket
●   │ │ ├─dbus.socket
●   │ │ ├─dm-event.socket
●   │ │ ├─iscsid.socket
●   │ │ ├─iscsiuio.socket
●   │ │ ├─pcscd.socket
●   │ │ ├─sssd-kcm.socket
●   │ │ ├─systemd-coredump.socket
●   │ │ ├─systemd-initctl.socket
●   │ │ ├─systemd-journald-audit.socket
●   │ │ ├─systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
●   │ │ ├─systemd-journald.socket
●   │ │ ├─systemd-udevd-control.socket
●   │ │ ├─systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
●   │ │ └─systemd-userdbd.socket
●   │ ├─sysinit.target
●   │ │ ├─dev-hugepages.mount
●   │ │ ├─dev-mqueue.mount
●   │ │ ├─dracut-shutdown.service
○   │ │ ├─iscsi-onboot.service
○   │ │ ├─iscsi-starter.service
●   │ │ ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
○   │ │ ├─ldconfig.service
●   │ │ ├─lvm2-lvmpolld.socket
●   │ │ ├─lvm2-monitor.service
●   │ │ ├─plymouth-read-write.service
●   │ │ ├─plymouth-start.service
●   │ │ ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
○   │ │ ├─selinux-autorelabel-mark.service
●   │ │ ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
●   │ │ ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
●   │ │ ├─sys-kernel-debug.mount
●   │ │ ├─sys-kernel-tracing.mount
○   │ │ ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
○   │ │ ├─systemd-binfmt.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-boot-random-seed.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-firstboot.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-hwdb-update.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-journal-catalog-update.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-journal-flush.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-journald.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-machine-id-commit.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-modules-load.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-network-generator.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-pcrmachine.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-pcrphase-sysinit.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-pcrphase.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-pstore.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-random-seed.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-repart.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-resolved.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-sysctl.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-sysusers.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-udev-trigger.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-udevd.service
○   │ │ ├─systemd-update-done.service
●   │ │ ├─systemd-update-utmp.service
●   │ │ ├─cryptsetup.target
●   │ │ ├─integritysetup.target
●   │ │ ├─local-fs.target
●   │ │ │ ├─-.mount
●   │ │ │ ├─boot-efi.mount
●   │ │ │ ├─media-Primary\x2dVolume.mount
●   │ │ │ ├─media-Secondary\x2dVolume.mount
○   │ │ │ ├─ostree-remount.service
●   │ │ │ ├─systemd-fsck-root.service
●   │ │ │ ├─systemd-remount-fs.service
●   │ │ │ └─tmp.mount
○   │ │ ├─swap.target
○   │ │ │ ├─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-83f883b3\x2dec24\x2d412a\x2db17e\x2d90251e3d5b0a.…
●   │ │ │ └─dev-zram0.swap
●   │ │ └─veritysetup.target
●   │ └─timers.target
●   │   ├─dnf-makecache.timer
●   │   ├─fstrim.timer
●   │   ├─logrotate.timer
●   │   ├─plocate-updatedb.timer
●   │   ├─raid-check.timer
●   │   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
●   │   └─unbound-anchor.timer
●   ├─getty.target
○   │ └─getty@tty1.service
●   ├─nfs-client.target
○   │ ├─auth-rpcgss-module.service
●   │ ├─rpc-statd-notify.service
●   │ └─remote-fs-pre.target
●   ├─remote-cryptsetup.target
●   └─remote-fs.target
●     └─nfs-client.target
○       ├─auth-rpcgss-module.service
●       ├─rpc-statd-notify.service
●       └─remote-fs-pre.target

And this is the output of the command systemd-analyze critical-chain.
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character. The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @48.691s └─multi-user.target @48.691s   └─mysqld.service @47.214s +1.476s
    └─network-online.target @47.210s
      └─network.target @47.210s
        └─wpa_supplicant.service @47.205s +4ms
          └─basic.target @46.155s
            └─dbus-broker.service @46.124s +29ms
              └─dbus.socket @46.113s
                └─sysinit.target @46.110s
                  └─systemd-resolved.service @46.029s +80ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @45.907s +103ms
                      └─local-fs.target @45.903s
                        └─tmp.mount @45.895s +6ms
                          └─systemd-journald.socket
                            └─system.slice
                              └─-.slice

Additionally, these are the contents of /etc/fstab.
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sat Apr  6 12:14:37 2024
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
UUID=0c14ae1c-b017-4009-9e5f-d34ad79f8f1c /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=452B-16BD          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
UUID=83f883b3-ec24-412a-b17e-90251e3d5b0a none                    swap    defaults        0 0
UUID=C07AC41E7AC412D8   /media/Primary-Volume                     ntfs    defaults        0 0
UUID=B0F8B100F8B0C5BE   /media/Secondary-Volume                   ntfs    defaults        0 0

I don't have a detailed idea about which service should be here and which shouldn't.
Please note that during the time of booting, no grub menu is displayed. My system directly boots into Fedora. I don't know why it is taking so much time on Userspace. It was fine 2 hours ago.

What does systemd-analyze critical-chain return? Add to your question, please.

@ajgringo619, added. Please check.

Hmmm...nothing in the systemd journal that jumps out? My Fedora Rawhide VM has a long boot time (as registered by systemd-analyze), but the login screen comes up pretty quick. You'll probably need to enable GRUB to show its progress during boot to see what's timing out. Can you also add your /etc/fstab?

@ajgringo619, added that, too. Regarding your concern regarding the grub, the grub boot-loader does not show up during the boot time despite the grub being installed on my system.
